# how to insert a piece of text in all headers in a document with VBA

Tags: vba, header, ms-word

all the answers I can find (and all the examples elsewhere on the web) are about very complicated insert operations (only on 1 header, or only odd pages, or not using select, or some such).

How do you insert a simple piece of text into all headers in a word document using VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions available to you - probably not what you want to hear, but when you use VBA you get more options as well as more things to think about!

I'd like to suggest two options that would work for most situations.

The first is to record a macro, then use the VBA code in the macro. This has the benefit of letting you see how the code reflects what is being done, and you can modify to suit your needs.

Another option would be to use the `.Headers` property, explained in detail [here](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV806051909990&lcid=1033&NS=WINWORD%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=83b9c541%2De462%2D4e1d%2Db1e3%2D1f76095a2055). This is a property of a section, and since each document contains an unknown number of sections you'll need to add a loop to apply this to each section.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did the one with .Headers and it worked perfectly.